# Wordpress theme customizations

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, themes

This theme came with WP bakery and I am old school I dont do page builders and in fact they are more complicated to use if anything. I just need help on my product page.

This is how i want it to look:

[image]

The theme is so sassy and any css I add to it is not taking I have fixed it for the most part but need a little guidance please help.

This is my site and how it looks currently https://photoshopfantasy.com/product/design-resources/

Comment: I think those two downvotes are due to the fact that we cannot offer such a wide solution - meaning build templates files or complete CSS solutions for you. This is the place to ask targeted questions. However, you should check out how to create and use a child theme. That would help get over the whole CSS precedence and also keep the original theme unchanged.

Comment: I am using a child theme. The problem is the child theme or the theme itself. I have added css but its just not taking it.

Comment: are you loading the css file correctly? try to do something like * {backgorund: black;} just for a moment to see if its even loading?

Comment: it is not and I fixed most of the issues, the problem Im having is on the product page im not sure if its woocommerce or the theme itself but all the text is on the right side even though i have left side bars enabled, the content is supposed to align left automatically but its not.  its aligned to the far right and I cant seem to figure out how to align it properly.

Comment: Thats a theme design issue. maybe your backend is in Hebrew / Arabic so wp has placed an RTL tag in your body tag. i really don't know - but now that your CSS is working you could just apply a "direction: ltr" or / and "text-align: left" - best of luck.

Comment: It is important you publish an answer to your question and close it (the question) later on ;) - good for the community.

Comment: ahh  i figured it out this theme developer is just awful he has two different areas to add custom css in the child theme and only one works. What a nightmare.

Comment: div.product div.summary, #content div.product div.summary {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:10px;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: If anyone is having issues with the zass wordpress theme I have literally mastered this hot mess of a theme literally had to recode it to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

OP's comment:

To get the gallery to display properly I used the woocommerce and product gallery images by we launch and I used a plugin that disabled gutenberg as it played very nasty with the zass wordpress handmade theme. I also had to hand code the sidebar in as it wouldn't display at all.

```css
div.product div.summary,
#content div.product div.summary {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

content div.product div.summary h1.heading-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

div.product p.price,
div.product .description,
div.product form.cart,
div.product form.variations_form.cart,
div.product .review,
div.product .summary {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

span.onsale {
  background-color: #a8dac2;
  padding: 15px 25px position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: To get the gallery to display properly I used the woocommerce and product gallery images by welaunch and I used a plugin that disabled gutenberg as it played very nasty with the zass wordpress handmade theme. I also had to hand code the sidebar in as it wouldnt display at all.